# Google Spreadsheet / gscript: Chart with custom data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Is it possible to create a chart in a spreadsheet with data that is not actually present in the sheet (calculated data)?

So instead of

```
chartBuilder.addRange(sheet.getRange("A2:A5"))
```

I want something like (pseudo code)

```
chartBuilder.addRange({0,1,2,8,15,35})
```

I guess I need to create a Range with custom data, but I couldn't find a solution in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way you could do this is if you used Charts and UI and showed it through the spreadsheet like so...

```
var data = Charts.newDataTable()
   .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, "Month")
   .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "In Store")
   .addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.NUMBER, "Online")
   .addRow(["January", 10, 1])
   .addRow(["February", 12, 1])
   .addRow(["March", 20, 2])
   .addRow(["April", 25, 3])
   .addRow(["May", 30, 4])
   .build();

var chart = Charts.newAreaChart()
   .setDataTable(data)
   .setStacked()
   .setRange(0, 40)
   .setTitle("Sales per Month")
   .build();

var uiApp = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("My Chart");
uiApp.add(chart);
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(uiApp);
```

Comment: Thank you for the contribution. I still hope there is a different way, because I would also like to easily update the chart whenever changes happen.

Comment: I believe if you use the new spreadsheets you could do so.
Look into the sidebar of the new sheets and the onEdit(e) function. I have not used the sidebar myself but I imagine the same kind of chart could be displayed within it while still allowing editing of the sheet. the onEdit(e) function would allow you to refresh the chart after edits.